# Рекуррентная формула

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста, помогите с заданием:
Разработать алгоритм и составить программу вычисления значений суммы S заданного ряда при различных значениях аргумента Х: во внутреннем цикле для фиксированного значения Х поочередно суммировать члены ряда, пока их абсолютная величина превышает заданную точность eps. Вычисление очередного член ряда осуществлять по рекуррентной формуле. Во внешнем цикле аргумент Х изменяется от 0,5 до 0,75 с шагом 0,05.

Ряд:

```
x*(3+x)/3! - x^3*(5+x)/5! + ... + (-1)^(n-1)*(x^(2n-1)*(2n+1+x))/((2n+1)!)
```

Где напортачила?

```
float Summ(float x, float eps)
{
    float elem,summ;
    int n=1;
    summ=elem=(x*(3+x))/6;
    while (x*(2*n+1+x)*(2*n+2)*(2*n+3)/(2*n+x)<eps)
    {
        elem*=-(x*(2*n+1+x)*(2*n+2)*(2*n+3))/(2*n+x);
        summ+=elem;
        n++;
    }
    return summ;
}
```

Comment: 1. Почему точность так вычисляется?

2. Как учитывается факториал при изменении `n`? Почему в `elem*= -...` в последней скобке `x` в знаменателе?

Comment: 1. Извините, немного не поняла вопроса. Речь идёт о том, что написано у меня, или о формулировке задания? 
Если касательно знака < в while, то только сейчас заметила: "пока их абсолютная величина превышает заданную точность eps". Результат выполнения программы от этого ближе к эталонному не стал.
2. Вроде, когда пыталась вывести рекуррентную формулу, получилось так. Если делить последующий член на предыдущий, то вроде факториал должен сократиться.

Comment: Благодарю! Вот так всегда: то плюс с минусом перепутаю, то ещё какая-то чепуха...

Answer (score 1):

x*(2*n+1+x) неправильно же! Вы потеряли квадрат.

Answer (score 1):

У вас еще условие цикла неверное. Вы сравниваете с eps отношение соседних элементов - а надо сравнивать значение очередного элемента. Кроме того, вы еще и не в ту сторону сравниваете.

```
summ=0;
for (elem = (x*(3+x))/6; elem >= eps; elem *= ...)
{
    summ+=elem;
}
```